# Update Column in a table using triggers while inserting value in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

So basically i have these 3 tables with their columns,

`tbl_equipment` ----> (`equip_id`,`equip_price`)

`tbl_equiporder` ----> (`equip_id`,`proj_no`,`qty`)

`tbl_project` -----> (`proj_no`,`proj_balance`)

i need to write a trigger that updates the `proj_balance` when inserting values in `tbl_equiporder` table.

formula that needs to be used is

```
balance = balance -(price*qty)
```

i need to get the qty value from `tbl_equiporder` while writing the insert statement for the same mentioned table so that i can use it to update the balance in `tbl_project`

i have written the following trigger to update the proj_balance on inserting in `tbl_equiporder` table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_equiporder
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON tbl_equiporder FOR EACH ROW    
  DECLARE
    t_equipid NUMBER(4);
    t_price   NUMBER(4);
    t_qty     NUMBER(4);
    t_balance NUMBER(4);
  BEGIN

    SELECT equip_id, equip_price INTO t_equipid, t_price
      FROM tbl_equipment@fit5043a
     WHERE equip_id = :new.equip_id;

    SELECT equip_qty INTO t_qty
      FROM tbl_equiporder
     WHERE equip_id = :new.equip_id;

    SELECT proj_balance INTO t_balance
      FROM tbl_project
     WHERE proj_no = :new.proj_no;

    t_balance := t_balance - (t_price * t_qty);

    UPDATE tbl_project
       SET proj_balance = t_balance
     WHERE proj_no = :new.proj_no;

  END;
```

When i wrote the insert statement

```
INSERT INTO tbl_equiporder VALUES (1, 101, 1);
```

it threw the following error

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO tbl_equiporder VALUES (1,101,'11-sep-13',1000,1)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table S24585181.TBL_EQUIPORDER is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "S24585181.TRIGGER_EQUIPORDER", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'S24585181.TRIGGER_EQUIPORDER'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read up about this error? You *can't* select from a table that you're altering in a trigger.

Remove the SELECT and just utilise the value, which is already available.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_equiporder 
 after insert or update or delete on tbl_equiporder
 for each row  

declare
   t_price number(4);
   t_qty number(4);
   t_balance number(4);
begin

   select equip_price into t_price 
     from tbl_equipment@fit5043a 
    where equip_id = :new.equip_id;

   select proj_balance into t_balance 
     from tbl_project 
    where proj_no = :new.proj_no;

    t_balance := t_balance -(t_price * :new.equip_qty);

   update tbl_project 
      set proj_balance = t_balance 
    where proj_no = :new.proj_no;

end;
```

I would be extremely cautious about all of this; you appear to be doing cross-database SELECTs in a trigger, which will slow it down massively. It seems as though it might be worth looking at your data model to see if it could be improved; even if it's something as simple as having a materialized view of `tbl_equipment` locally.

You were also selecting unnecessary data across a database link, don't. I've removed it

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried running the above query. And I am still getting the same error. Am i supposed to get rid of the selects ? How will i get the values i am supposed to compare without the select ?

Comment: You can't be getting exactly the same error @Advait... can you copy and paste the _exact_ error?

Comment: Hi Ben, I am getting the following error
Error starting at line 1 in command:
INSERT INTO tbl_equiporder VALUES (1,101,'11-sep-13',1000,1)
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table S24585181.TBL_EQUIPORDER is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "S24585181.TRIGGER_EQUIPMENT", line 10
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'S24585181.TRIGGER_EQUIPMENT'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"

Comment: *Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

Comment: In that case you're not using the trigger I've changed as it does not read from `TBL_EQUIPORDER`; you can see that.

Comment: ive used exactly the same code that you sent, but it still threw the same error

Comment: Ah, look at the trigger name in the error; you have a second trigger on the table that has the same problem.